# sum calculated values from text field in Access Report

Tags: ms-access-2016

I am hoping the images I have pasted are visible to you.

I have a report that is calculating a fractional value (for an election)

I want to add these values together.    I tried the =Sum and used running sum, and have had more success with =NZ.    But the most I can get is the value of the last field rather than the total of all the fields in that column.

Hope you can help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHZl8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91CHv.png)

Comment: Sum will work on the data in Detail section not in Header section. Consider having your data in Detail section to have all the aggregate functions working

Comment: Thanks - but the report won't format as I want it unless it is in the header section.

Comment: I see in the picture that your data is in tabular format that normally can be formatted in Detail section.

Comment: ah - I will have a look - thanks